# Appengine - converting from db.Model to ndb.Model?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a bunch of data defined as db.Model and I want to convert it to ndb.Model.

I tried just changing from db to ndb like so:

```py
class Temp(db.Model):
  temperature = db.FloatProperty() 

class Temp(ndb.Model):
  temperature = ndb.FloatProperty()
```

The thing is I can query the old values(the db-values) with the ndb definition of temp. But I dont seem to be able to store ndb values when I already have db-values with the same model-name.

Comment: can you show how you are trying to save new values?

Comment: what makes you think you cant save new values? do you get an error? does it not return the new values? the model definition above is right .

Answer (score 3):

Are you getting any specific errors?

In this [thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/appengine-ndb-discuss/ar8ZIzGkF84%5B1-25%5D) is explained that

> You could even have two versions of the app, one using db and one using ndb, reading and
>   writing the same entities in the datastore.

Also take a look to this [cheat sheet](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1AefylbadN456_Z7BZOpZEXDq8cR8LYu7QgI7bt5V0Iw/edit?ndplr=1&pli=1) (also referenced in the thread) for converting one db app to an ndb one.

Comment: The excellent cheat sheet has been copied to the official NDB docs https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/db_to_ndb. Apart from format, it looks to be the same thing for now. Suspect the cheatsheet won't be maintained.